# ¿Como incrementar datos pasados por post en un array? PHP

Tags: php, array

Quiero enviar datos en un formulario y que se vayan incrementando los datos ahí. Es decir, que cada vez que se use el formulario, no se reemplacen los datos actuales por los anteriores sino que mi array vaya creciendo.

Intenté hacerlo pero se va reemplazando con lo ingresado en el momento:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="datos.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
    <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="apellido">
    <button type="submit" name="enviar">Enviar</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
    $enviar=$_POST['enviar'];

    getData($nombre, $apellido);

    function getData($nombre, $apellido){

        $usuarios = array();
        $usuariosIngresados=0;

        $usuario = array();
        $usuario['nombre']=$nombre;
        $usuario['apellido']=$apellido;
        $usuarios[$usuariosIngresados]=$usuario;
        $usuariosIngresados++;

        echo json_encode( $usuarios);
    }
?>
```

Comment: por que no envías el formulario a través de ajax y vas guardando el formulario en un array en js

Comment: @Henrymarcazeballos porque lo tengo que hacer con php :I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias probar usando SESSIONES, aquí en este pequeño ejemplo se comprueba si existe la session del array, si existe solo agrega el nombre y apellido correspondiente , de lo contrario la crea y añade los valores, asi al mantenerse la sesion ira incrementando los datos como tu quieres.

Solo te bastaria con reemplazar las variables por las tuyas y validar que el POST no venga vacío

```
session_start();

$nombre = 'Pepito';
$apellido = 'Estrada';

if(isset($_SESSION['arr'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['arr'] , array('nombre' => $nombre , 'apellido' => $apellido));
}else{
    $_SESSION['arr'] = [];
    array_push($_SESSION['arr'] , array('nombre' => $nombre , 'apellido' => $apellido));
}

var_dump($_SESSION['arr']);
```

Si necesitas alguna modificación comentame